# How many values of an array in a MySQL string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a simple array with some values:

```
$firstArray = array (
  ['val1'] => 'a',
  ['val2'] => 'b',
  ['val3'] => 'c'
);
```

and I would like to find how many values of this array appear in every line of a MySQL table like this one:

```
| ID |  Name  |    Val    |
| 01 | voice1 | a,c,d,e   |    // it should return 2 (a and c)
| 02 | voice2 | a,b,c,d,f |    // it should return 3 (a,b and c)
```

The best thing should be to have an array with ID, name, and how many values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FIND_IN_SET that will return you the position of the matched value and convert it to 1 or 0 with the SIGN function.

```
select
    SIGN(FIND_IN_SET('a', texte)) +
    SIGN(FIND_IN_SET('b', texte)) +
    SIGN(FIND_IN_SET('c', texte))
from your_table;
```

This returns exactly what you expected with your test data-set.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay!

Comment: Sorry... a part of the question was "The best thing should be to have an array with ID, name, and how many values"... how to obtain it?

Comment: You just have to add: "ID,  name, " just after the select.